# Relative path in img tag to the same image from 2 files in the same folder is different

Tags: html, image, coldfusion, loading, relative-path

I have 2 cfm pages in the same folder, doing very similar things. They both produce some reports for user related data. I recently added a loading image to one because some of the queries to generate the reports can take a while.

The second page is a new but very similar page. Since the pages are in the same folder I figured the relative path to the loading image should be the same. However the new page is giving a 404 response for the image request, and when I check the http request header it is adding an extra folder to the relative path and thus unable to find the image.

```html
<img src="../../../Graphics/General/loading.gif">
```

They are both very similar pages in that they display a simple form, then run some queries and generate a table to display the relevant data to the user. However the relative path above produces "Dev/Menu/Graphics/General/loading.gif" in one page and "Dev/Graphics/General/loading.gif" on the other.

I've since figured out that adding an extra "../" to the image path in the new file has fixed it for the new page, however I am at a loss for why this fix was necessary and why it worked.

```html
<img src="../../../../Graphics/General/loading.gif">
```

I would expect that since both pages are in the same exact folder, that the relative path to the given image would be exactly the same. I am mostly just curious why that is not the case.

Comment: Are you doing anything with iframes? Or do the pages have a different base tag path? Do you have links that look like directories but not? Something like `index.cfm/myreport` ?

Comment: There is a navbar and a side menu for navigation and individual pages are loaded into an iframe. As for the rest of your questions, I do not believe so, but I am still new to CF and could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The two reports are in the same folder. Are you loading these pages directly?

```
 yourSite.com/reports/report1.cfm
 yourSite.com/reports/report2.cfm
```

Or are these files loaded via other parent pages?

```
 yourSite.com/some/other/folder/with/include_report1.cfm
 yourSite.com/yet/another/folder/that/contains/include_report2.cfm
```

Often, it's better to load images directly from web root in order to avoid relative pathing issues like these. If the `Graphics` folder is at the root, then just reference the image in both files like so:

```
<img src="/Graphics/General/loading.gif">
```

This way, it doesn't matter what file includes them and renders the final HTML to the browser, the image will be referenced from the web root no matter what.